# No option to 'Get Latest' in VS2010 with TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using VS2010 and have suddenly lost the option to get latest code using TFS in my solution. In the 'Team Explorer' tab I also cannot expand the 'Source Control' option. Everything else seems ok as far as I can see.

This *may* have something to do with getting IE7 installed on Windows 7 (I know, i know!!) which cocked everything up. A re-register of dlls appeared to have fixed things, but this is being problematic.

Operating system, as said above, is Windows 7 32 bit.

Any thoughts or pointers?

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check you have a connection to the TFS server.
2. Check your workspace mapping.
3. What does `tf get` from the command line do?
4. What does `tf get /force` from the command line do? (Has the server got a different idea of you workspace's state then it should?)

Comment: It basically hangs. Not getting any response from either command

Comment: @user1374496: How are you doing step #1?

Comment: I can connect to Source Control to see all the projects and branches perfectly well - it's just I am missing any of the Source control options in me context menu in the solution. I can even 'Get Latest' Version' if i am viewing Source Control and hit the Get Latest Version button - but that is the ONLY way i can get latest version. It appears all my context menu options for source control have vanished!

Comment: @user1374496 Have you viewed your workspace: go in and edit it (you don't need to save changes). Be completely sure it is correct (much of version control before TFS11 depends on having a working workspace). Also ensure the current workspace is what you expect it to be.